# Background gradient reacts to window size but shouldn't

Tags: html, css

I made the background:

`background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgb(107, 134, 145) 0%, rgb(43, 57, 67) 100%);`

The center off the background reacts to resizing of the window. Its always in the center of the visible window. I want the center of the background to be at the center of the fullscreen and then remain fixed regardless of the height of the window?

Fixed it somehow:

Fixed it with:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-  stop(0%,#eee), color-stop(100%,#999));

background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #eee 0%,#999 100%);
```

Instead of background-image just background did the trick. The center of the gradient effects stays in the middle despite resizing.

Comment: Try replicating your issue in a jsFiddle.

Comment: React's how? Do you mean the centre moves...that would be normal (I think) it's centered on the body (I assume) and if that changes height...the center moves accordingly.

Comment: Yes the center moves with the center off the visible part of the page but that looks bad. Besides, i try to learn of a different page which has the desired effect but not the adjusting center. I can't manage to reproduce the effect

Comment: Make a Jsfiddle as it is now and we can work on it.

Comment: Managed to fix it. Thanks for your time.